# Ruby and Rails. Joining empty span and text

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new to rails and ruby. I'm trying to join empty span with bootstrap icon generated by `tag 'span', class: "glyphicon glyphicon-" + icon_name` and text

```
icon_span = tag 'span', class: "glyphicon glyphicon-" + icon_name
link_to icon_span + item[:title], item[:link]
```

I'm waiting for something like this

```
<a href=".."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-..."></span> Link</a>
```

But I'm getting a text inside span like

```
<a href=".."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-..."> Link</span></a>
```

What's the magic going on? How can I get what I want?

Comment: tried the code on the console and work without any problem... it's that the _same code_ that you are running?

Comment: Yes. It wraps text with span

Comment: @wacko It's pretty strange but I get what I need in console

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
link_to icon_span + item[:title], item[:link] do
  tag 'span', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-' + icon_name
end
```

I haven't tested this but I believe this should work out well.

Comment: the link should wrap the span and not viceversa

Comment: I edited the code to be how you expected. This should resolve your issue.